# How to update sql in the same column?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Hello can anyone please help me? i'm trying to update multiple rows with the condition of

> script = '0'

```
UPDATE item_db2
SET script = 'bonus bDef,1;'
WHERE script = '0'
```

in the script column there are others have already values. i just wanted to update the rows that have script values of "0"

but this script i have seems to be replacing all script column not following the condition.

Comment: Your code seems fine to me.

Comment: show the `CREATE TABLE` and some example data

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong data type for your script column.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4bkRiNTJ create table.

Comment: Can you use varchar(500) or so for script column instead of text?

Comment: Okay thanks it now work with varchar(500) 
can i ask something about column? i'd like to use the column script of table item_db3 into item_db2. I don't know what to use code.